# How to convert String to Reader in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a method which reads a file and returns a string, but I wanted to return a reader. I want to convert the string to a reader, or I want to read the file and return the reader. How can I do this?

Comment: String Reader is working fine. I have used filereader instead of writing my own method this is simpler. (Reader)new FileReader(filePath);

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use [`java.io.StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html): `return new StringReader(string);`.

Next time you need a reader, you can check the "Direct known subclasses" of the [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) class. Same goes for `InputStream`, etc. The place to start is the javadoc - it contains quite a lot of useful information.

But for your task at hand, you'd better follow Jon Lin' advice of simply using a `FileReader`. There is no need to go through `String`. (For that, my advice from the previous paragraph applies as well)

Comment: I'd add that if you're using Eclipse, pulling up a tree of all known subclasses for any type is as easy as hitting F4 when the cursor is on the type (e.g. `Reader`). I presume other IDEs are similarly equipped. Tremendously helpful in these situations.

Comment: This answers the *literal* question in the title and is probably why 90% came here. But **@JonLin**'s answer has a better solution for the specific situation described by OP.

Answer (score 11):

Or you can simply create a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) and return that.

Comment: He says he has a method that reads a file and he wants to return a Reader instead of a String

Answer (score 10):

You can use [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) class from `java.io` package.

```
String stringToBeParsed = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringToBeParsed);
```

Comment: "*jumpS*", not "*jumpED*", otherwise not all 26 characters are used ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code,

```
FileInputStream in = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String tempString = null;
    Reader initialReader;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        initialReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        char[] arr = new char[8 * 1024];
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        int numCharsRead;
        while ((numCharsRead = initialReader.read(arr, 0, arr.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.append(arr, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String targetString = buffer.toString();

        result = IOUtils.toByteArray(targetString);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```